# Git autocomplete not working on macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: macos, bash, git, iterm2

I've tried everything I've found on the internet but nothing seems to work. Things I've tried:

- Instruction in the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Bash) for bash environments
- This [medium post](https://medium.com/@dilankam/enable-auto-completion-of-git-commands-on-mac-os-mojave-10-14-2d692c100bc)
- Tried with `brew install bash-completion` and `brew install bash-completion@2`

  - With each of those versions I tried adding to .bash_profile multiple different things
- Installing git from homebrew
- Using only .bash_profile and then only .bashrc
- Just copying [git_completion.bash](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) and adding the file as a source in both .bash_profile and .bashrc

From what I understood, I need git_completion.bash, but that depends on bash-completion. Is that correct? How can I check that bash-completion is working?

I need a bulletproof sequence of steps that will result on git autocomplete working on my terminal if that's even possible. If I need an initial state, like git or bash versions, or a git configuration, that'd be important to know as well.

I'm using:

- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.5
- Terminal: iTerm2 Build 3.3.8
- Git: git version 2.13.5 (Apple Git-94)
- Bash: GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)

Thanks!

Comment: I got it working using zsh instead of bash. I followed the instructions here https://medium.com/@oliverspryn/adding-git-completion-to-zsh-60f3b0e7ffbc